# simple form vs continuous form

Tags: present-continuous, present-simple

What is the difference between them in terms of meaning?

> Everywhere you go nowadays people seem to be speaking English.
>
> Everywhere you go nowadays people seem to speak English.

Answer (score 2):

**Present Simple** can express:

a. Action that happens again. (like a habit)

b. Fact that is always true.

c. Fact that is true for a long time.

**Present** can express:

a. Activity that is now.

b. Activity that is not necessarily happening at the moment of speaking but is happening around now.

c. Temporary activity.

d. Planned future arrangement.

Answer (score 1):

People often use the two sentences to mean the same thing. However, the first sentence means that everywhere you go nowadays people are always talking, and that their talk is in English. The second sentence means that everyone can speak English.